What is the solution to the Problem of Child Cancer?
Why would an all-powerful God allow young children to have terminal diseases like cancer? Why would an omnipotent and omnibenevolent deity allow innocent younglings to experience such profound pain and early death?
This question is different from any general questions concerning the Problem of Evil, because it focuses on a particular kind of evil that doesn't seem to lead to any greater good, doesn't seem to be necessary for free will and doesn't seem to be covered by any classical theodicies. There is a distinction between General Problem of Evil ("why would God allow evil in general") and Special Problem of Evil ("why would God allow this particular evil").

@jaredad7 I have edited the question as you requested. Thank you for notifying me!

How do you expect any answer to be significantly different from the answers to the Problem of Childhood Leukemia, or School Bus Crashes, or Starvation, or …? And how would it be different from Adult Cancer?

The solution is that this is a tragedy, but not an evil. This makes your question a frame issue. Let me explain.

Events and circumstances that are undesired, unwanted, or harmful come in 2 general categories. (I will often also cause these "suffering")

Tragedy: These are events/circumstances that could not be avoided by those experiencing it, nor prevented by others.
Evil: Are similar, but they are "unnecessary" because they could have been avoided or prevented.

The suffering of people within a re-education camp is an Evil. It is imposed by someone else on another. (Or to use a child as an example, abortion is also evil)
The suffering of anyone (child or adult) with cancer is (still) unpreventable, it was not caused to harm by someone else.

So now that we have defined "evil" and "tragedy" your question is clearly about "Why does God allow tragedies?"

Most people, including many Orthodox Christians, have had their vision of God shaped by a Western theology that begins with philosophical abstractions. Their notion of God begins with the image of One who is omniscient and omnipotent, a God of Justice who demands justice from us under threat of punishment if we do not conform to his will, his law.
From an Orthodox perspective, however, we need to begin not with the image of “God on high,” but with the more powerful and more poignant image of the Cross. That image does not explain in rational terms the mystery of innocent suffering; nothing in this life does or can (that is why it is “suffering” and not merely pain). But it does tell us what is essential: that “if I make my bed in Sheol, Thou art there!” (Ps. 38/39). All we can finally say about tragedies such as the one in Haiti, or the tsunami of a couple of years ago, or the death of a little child on the highway, is that Christ is present with us, to share totally our loss, our grief and our pain. As the Paschal icon so dramatically and beautifully depicts it, Christ descends again and again into the depths of our hell, to reach out his hand to grasp ours, and to lift us from the darkness into his radiant light. For all of those trapped under the ruins, Christ is there, sharing their agony to the bitter end. He is with those who grieve the loss of loved ones, bearing their sorrow and anguish as well. As the service of Great Compline declares, he is “God with us!” Not in the first place as a God of righteousness and judgment, but as the God of boundless love, who remains, in Pascal’s words, “in agony until the end of the world.”
If we begin with the Cross, rather than with some abstract notion of divine omnipotence, then we can see that God and we ourselves are still engaged in a massive cosmic struggle. The Cross and Resurrection ended Satan’s sovereignty over the world and over our individual destinies. Yet the struggle continues, just as sin continues, as natural disasters continue, and will do so until Christ comes again in glory. Once more we need to remind ourselves: there is profound significance in the fact that at the Empty Tomb the angel speaks of Christ not as “the Risen One,” but as “the Crucified One” (Matt & Mk). The risen and glorified Christ remains “the Crucified One” in the life and experience of every one who seeks him, perhaps first of all those who cry out to him from under the rubble.
Fr. John Breck, responding to the Earthquake in Haiti


The reason tragedy occurs, is because we still live in the world where Adam and Eve doubted the Goodness of God. We still suffer the unnatural effects of sin, our souls are split from our bodies, we still die, and we still live in the world where the devil as well as humanity continue to corrupt the world more and more. Even though we are blessed to live in the period after the resurrection, where it is more clear than ever that the demons and the devil will fail... they still fight back, they still thinks they can win... (even though they literally cannot do anything without God's express permission)
So we live in a corrupted world and cancer is literally a corruption of the body, our own bodies growing corrupted cells. It is almost a poetic example of how the consequences of sin affect everyone.

Short answer: You described a type of suffering that is a tragedy, but is not evil. Regardless, the reason tragedy and evil exist is because of us. Even cancer and earthquakes are ultimately because of the sin of doubt. The doubt that God actually loves us.

Is cancer a tragedy or man made? From biblical perspective, "Life is in the blood", and it is in the blood where cancer start, by contaminating or injecting the blood with toxic substances, cancer begin to flourish. And the next one, Did Adam and Eve doubted the goodness of God?

@jongricafort Cancer is a tragedy for most who gets it today. In the case of children it is definitely a tragedy. A smoker with lung cancer? Perhaps not. Context is important. If Adam and Eve did not doubt, why did they question what God instructed?

Is cancer man made? I said Yes, because cancer starts from the blood circulation, if toxins enters the blood, then for sure, cancer will flourish. "Life is in the blood. "-Leviticus17:11. Adam did not doubt, even Eve did not doubt. What happen is, the Serpent introduce doubt or dubia, and Eve defended it but still fall into it, because Eve, defended herself with white lies.

@jongricafort I would submit that all illness and death is not man made. It is a natural consequence. It is not directly our fault, just like death is not God's fault. Those who sin, suffer. Not from being punished, but from the natural consequences of sin itself. Those lie eventually get caught or end up so twisted that they cannot trust anything. The natural result of sin is suffering and death. Just like the natural result of burning a candle is soot and flame. Cancer is not "man made" it is "a natural result of sin". (Punishment is God's alone, at the 2nd coming)

"Cancer is not "man made" it is "a natural result of sin". "??? Your opinion go against the biblical teaching, even Jesus wont agree on that. Have you ever heard of the word "carcinogenic", and where do we get this stuff? Who made it? and somehow find its way in our food, drinks, medicine, and even in the air we breathe? and ofcourse, its find its way into our blood, like the "serpent" in the garden, but this time, the serpent uses modern day instruments to inject poisonous toxins directly in our blood, and most people are still clueless like you.

@jongricafort What about all the cancers that occur without toxins? We can have a conversation in chat. But please refrain from insults, I'm likely more aware of issues than you give me credit for. Like how Fauci finally admitted they couldn't provide a single test for the vaccines for children at all.  Or how I know more people who died mysteriously during covid, then actually died from the illness. But I try to stay to the theological here on this SE. We can however get into the fun stuff in chat... Make a room and invite me if you wish. :)
